# subsample a df multiple times in a pipe R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, tidyverse

I have a df with 50 rows. I want to simulate it as if I only had 5 of those rows, but I want to do that a bunch of times. I know I could do this separately and bind them all together, but that's dumb. Hoping there's a way with one command. I'm thinking some sort of `map()` or `do{}` but I'm not too familiar with those at the moment.

I want to stay in tidyverse syntax if possible because the `%>%` pipe will continue.

```
# make df
df <- data.frame(sample=c(1:50),
                 y = sample(1:100, 50, replace=T) )


# sample df
df %>% 
  sample_n(5) %>%
  mutate(simulation = 1) 

# so this does what I want once, but I want to repeat this, say, 20 times. 


# desired output:

  sample   y simulation
1     34   4          1
2      7   1          1
3     26  59          1
4     41  56          1
5     44  82          1
6     25   9          2
7     40  11          2
8     13  39          2
9     6   56          2
10    24  80          3
11    36  41          3
12     9   2          3
13    11  56          3
14     1  36          3
15    25   8          3
# and so on to 20 simulations.
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are packages for simulation analysis using pipes have you tried the infer package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replicate(..., simplify=FALSE)` is going to do what you need *quickly*, and then you can bind it later.

```r
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(replicate(3, sample_n(df, 5), simplify = FALSE),
          .id = "simulation")
#    simulation sample  y
# 1           1     12  3
# 2           1     42 22
# 3           1     14 50
# 4           1      3  6
# 5           1     45 46
# 6           2      2  9
# 7           2     30 18
# 8           2     24 66
# 9           2     50 62
# 10          2     21 96
# 11          3      3  6
# 12          3     33 47
# 13          3     25 12
# 14          3     32 96
# 15          3     20  4
```

Or wholly within tidyverse:

```r
purrr::map_dfr(1:3, ~ sample_n(df, 5), .id = "simulation")
```

Comment: thanks- I like this version, but I'm having some trouble with the whole tidy version, because I need it to pipe in as well.

Like, 
`
df %>% 
  map_dfr(1:2, ~ sample_n( . , 5), .id="simulation")
`
except that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Yup: `df %>% replicate(3, ., simplify = FALSE) %>% map_dfr(~ sample_n(., 5), .id = "simulation")`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> -- Attaching packages ---------------------------------------------------------- tidymodels 0.1.0 --
#> v broom     0.5.6      v recipes   0.1.12
#> v dials     0.0.6      v rsample   0.0.7 
#> v dplyr     1.0.0      v tibble    3.0.1 
#> v ggplot2   3.3.1      v tune      0.1.0 
#> v infer     0.5.1      v workflows 0.1.1 
#> v parsnip   0.1.1      v yardstick 0.0.6 
#> v purrr     0.3.4
#> -- Conflicts ------------------------------------------------------------- tidymodels_conflicts() --
#> x purrr::discard()  masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()   masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()      masks stats::lag()
#> x ggplot2::margin() masks dials::margin()
#> x recipes::step()   masks stats::step()


df <- data.frame(sample=c(1:50),
                 y = sample(1:100, 50, replace=T) )

df %>% 
  specify(formula = y ~ sample) %>%
  hypothesize(null = "independence") %>% 
  generate(reps = 100,type = "permute") %>%
  slice_head(n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 500 x 3
#> # Groups:   replicate [100]
#>        y sample replicate
#>    <int>  <int>     <int>
#>  1    63      1         1
#>  2    53      2         1
#>  3    57      3         1
#>  4    44      4         1
#>  5    82      5         1
#>  6    92      1         2
#>  7    83      2         2
#>  8    89      3         2
#>  9    17      4         2
#> 10    35      5         2
#> # ... with 490 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think it is cool to add that permutation should not be used to test anything other than independence